# cPanel throwing 503 error after editing a file in the www directory

Tags: cpanel, centos7

I am struggling with this particular issue and cPanel's documentation really has not been any help.

This is a fresh setup of centOS7 (clean install) and cPanel for provisioning.

I am my own host - with a static IP.

I can login to cPanel on both common ports (2087 root and 2083 )

Ports 80,443,21,22 and 3306 are open

Here is my issue in a nutshell:

When I create an account in cPanel and then login as that account I can  create a placeholder index.php file that simply just says "hi".

The problem is. After I edit the file once; if I try to create any other file  or even edit the index.php file a second time? the domain will throw a 503 error. If I try to chmod the public_html folder in any way? cPanel throws a 503 error. If I try to extract my gitHub repo into the www folder? cPanel throws a 503 error.

The only way to fix it is to Terminate/Delete the account and then re-create it. So this is an endless loop of working/busted/working/busted.

The cPanel documentation has really been of zero help. Their support staff doesn't seem to have a clue either.

Is there a security setting I am missing? I have checked the log files. It is not giving me any info about why it is throwing an 503.

I have been going in circles for a day on this so any help is appreciated.

```
<?php
// Sample Placeholder Page
?>

<h1>This is a sample placeholder for cPanel</h1>
```

I expect that when editing a file such as index.php it should load properly.

The output is a 503 error after editing the file more than once or adding any other file.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was caused by a corrupted PHP install by Easy Apache. Running a manual rebuild and switching from PHP 7.2 to 7.3 fixed the issue.